# Run a command after vc-git-log-outgoing

Tags: spacemacs, vc, vc-mode

I'm trying to fix a problem with this project: https://github.com/domtronn/spaceline-all-the-icons.el

Specifically this code which is supposed to count the number of commits ahead of another branch the current branch is: https://github.com/domtronn/spaceline-all-the-icons.el/blob/master/spaceline-all-the-icons-segments.el#L818

The problem is that `vc-git-log-outgoing` is asynchronous, and the `count-lines` stuff ends up counting the lines before `vc-git-log-outgoing` completes - so it always returns 0.

I've been able to get it to "work" with hacks like `(sit-for 0.1)` but this feels wrong. What's the correct way to modify this code so that `count-lines` only happens *after* `vc-git-log-outgoing` completes?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info